# Crystal Reports Number formatting whole number and decimals

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am using VS2010 and Crystal reports plug-in and getting a value from stored procedure.
The values on this field are whole numbers and some of the numbers do have decimals.

```
Col 1
-----
42
25,725
5.22
```

When I right-click and format object. I am unable to achieve this. If I enable decimal it is displaying

```
42.00
25,725.00
5.22
```

How can I achieve the format that I have mentioned. I appreciate your support.

I tried the following formula:

```
//FieldOne is float
//Probably don't need the else. 

If InStr(ToText({proc1;1.FieldOne}),".") > 0 THEN
Truncate({Proc1;1.FieldOne},2)
Else
Truncate({Proc1;1.FieldOne})
```

I am getting a "string is required here." error

Answer (score 0):

When you right-click on the field and chose Format Field, click on the Number tab and then on customize. Create a formula in the Decimals option to not show a decimal if there is no "." in the value and to show 2 decimals if there is a "." in the value.

Comment: could you please check the formula in the question and let me know? I appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Try: If InStr(cStr({proc1;1.FieldOne}),".") > 0 THEN 2 ELSE 0

Comment: What type is {proc1;1.FieldOne}?

Comment: It is Float data type.

Comment: Hmmm...try this: stringvar x := totext({proc1;1.FieldOne}) Then a new line: if InStr(x, ".") > 0 then 2 else 0

Comment: Yes use string data type and it will show the value as it is.

Answer (score 0):

There are number of options when you will select Format Object:
[image]

and Within Custom Style we have;
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, If my question is not clear. I am aware of this. My question is when you use this it will display 42.00
25,725.00
5.22 but I want 42 and the 25,725 and 5.22

Comment: Ok so you mean that when there are decimals then must show decimals and when its whole number than as a whole number only?..I think you must add the textobject as string only so whatever value is coming, it will be shown simply.